# Why don't we have statistics for each group?

Tags: r, dataframe

Input:

```
library("UsingR")
library("dplyr")
data("kid.weights")
attach(Kid.weights)
df <- data.frame(gender[1:6],
                 weight[1:6],
                 height[1:6],
                 Kg=weight[1:6] * 0.453592,
                 M=height[1:6] * 0.0254)

df
df %>%
  group_by(df$gender) %>%
  summarise(mean(df$weight))
```

Output:

```
> df %>%
+   group_by(df$gender) %>%
+   summarise(mean(df$weight))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  `df$gender` `mean(df$weight)`
  <fct>                   <dbl>
1 F                        58.3
2 M                        58.3
```

I want to make data frame for mean(weight(kg)) or median(weight(kg)) to gender.
but it is not working. looks like.
how to it solve?

Comment: Remove the `df$` bits, dplyr looks inside the passed dataframe first withe the prefix you force it to use the original ungrouped one: `df %>% group_by(gender) %>% summarise(mean(weight))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Once you use `%>%` you don't need to reference to `df` anymore:

```
df %>%
  group_by(gender) %>%
  summarise(mean(weight))
```

`%>%` is a pipeline which makes you accessible to the columns directly, on each group, `df$gender` and `df$weight` would give you the whole column.

Comment: This explanation is inaccurate: the behaviour has nothing to do with `%>%`, it’s solely due to the functions themselves.